# Get totals of each month a year including the month with no result

Tags: php, mysql

I want to echo the total of invoices created per month.

Code below is working so far but I need a 0 if there is no result in a month.

```
$sql = "SELECT MONTH( invoice_date ) AS MONTH, SUM(`invoice`.`total`) as total
    FROM `invoices`
    WHERE YEAR(invoice_date) = '2019'
    GROUP BY MONTH(invoice_date)";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $total = $data['total'];
    $month = $data['month'];
}
```

What I want is this:

```
Jan 500
Feb 300
Mar 0
Apr 500
etc...
```

What I get is this

Jan 500
Feb 300
Apr 500

... because there is no entry with Mar in my DB.

If I do the query in a loop for each month it's working fine but I know I shouldn't use it this way and there is a better way!?

Comment: Because there is no entry for Mar in your invoice table, it has nothing to select.

The query cannot display what is not in your table with your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `UNION ALL` create a query which returns all the month numbers 1-12 and LEFT JOIN to your query:

```
SELECT m.MONTH, COALESCE(t.total, 0)
FROM (
  SELECT 1 AS MONTH UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL
  SELECT 9 UNION ALL SELECT 10 UNION ALL SELECT 11 UNION ALL SELECT 12
) AS m LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT MONTH( invoice_date ) AS MONTH, SUM(`invoice`.`total`) as total
  FROM `invoices`
  WHERE YEAR(invoice_date) = '2019'
  GROUP BY MONTH(invoice_date)
) AS t ON t.MONTH = m.MONTH
```